# jade view didn't render properly in my case

Tags: node.js, pug

```
p 
 | user / a.active(href="#{back_url}") james
```

I even tried

```
p 
 | user / 
 | a.active(href="#{back_url}") james
```

No error in my terminal, just the html is broken. I want it to be like this

```
<p>user / <a class="active" href="link">james</a></p>
```

Comment: What does the HTML you expect look like vs what you are getting?

Comment: <p>user / <a class="active">james</a></p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
p
 | user / 
 a.active(href='link') james
```

Try http://html2jade.org/

Answer (score 0):

you would not use '|' if you want to put an html element, it is actually used for putting the text, for example as u used it for putting in text "user /"

also, as per my coding pattern preference i'll write it as :

```
p 
 | user / 
 a.active(href="#{back_url}") 
   | james
```